# After sleep state, PC with Xubuntu doesn't let me shut down the system

Tags: networking, suspend, shutdown

I have been using Xubuntu as my main system for 3 weeks, but I noticed only today that after the PC has woken up from the sleep state it doesn't let me shut down the system. I tried to shut down by using `sudo shutdown now` but what I get is

```
Failed to execute operation: There's already a shutdown or sleep operation in progress
```

There is another problem as well: when the PC wakes from sleep it can't connect to the Network (I only use Ethernet connection) but it tells me that there is no connection available.

My PC works flawlessly until it goes in sleep state, I can't figure out what is causing my machine not to work when it wakes from sleep state.

I've got a Intel 4790k with Nvidia 970 and 8GB (with 16GB swap)

Comment: What happens if you execute **sudo shutdown now** in terminal?

Comment: Failed to execute operation: There's already a shutdown or sleep operation in progress

Comment: Try also **halt --verbose** and **poweroff --verbose**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered that was causing this strange behavior was the propietary Nvidia driver. 
Disabling propietary and using open source drivers has solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on arch linux with nvidia 1060 (387 driver)

It seems that this issue was closely related to lightdm and light-locker. light-locker switches VT to lightdm's one and suspend action is going on in parallel. Seems nvidia cannot handle this correctly.

You may switch display manager to gdm or sddm.

Link to the duplicate question: https://superuser.com/questions/1049823/after-sleep-state-pc-with-linux-doesnt-let-me-shut-down-the-system

Nvidida forum: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025478/linux/cannot-suspend-after-some-time-of-idle/